# Setting jQuery Button Width input type="button"

Tags: jquery, html, css, input, size

Okay so I am using jQuery Mobile in a simple Golf Score Card App. I use this code to get the total at the end of a form.

```
<input id="total" type="text" name="total" value="" readonly="readonly" /> 
<p><input type="button" value="=" onclick="total.value=getTotalB(this.form)" />
<p><input type="reset" onClick="reset()" value="-"/>
</form>
```

I need the input type="button" and the reset to be about 10px. I have tried style="width". I not sure what the easiest way is to size these buttons is. Any help?

Comment: try setting a `style="margin: 10px"` to `type="button" `

Comment: Can you explain more? I didn't understood a thing.

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest case, you could try:

```
input {
    width: 10px;
}
```

or else add classes to be more specific.

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/jV8FV/

Comment: So yeah works perfect in the fiddle, threw this in my document. <style>

input {
    width: 10px;
}

</style>  Think it's fighting with jquery mobile? It doesn't work out for some reason

Comment: I am guessing that jQuery Mobile has a CSS rule that is quite specific for the input buttons.  If this is the case, you need to make your custom CSS rule more specific than any pre-existing CSS rules from the jQuery Mobile styling.

Answer (score 0):

Just give them a similar class, then style it using CSS:

Working example:

```
<html><head>

<style type='text/css'>
input.small {
    width:10px;  /* Apply to input tags with class "small" */
}

</style>

</head><body><form>

<input id="total" type="text" name="total" value="" readonly="readonly" />
<input class='small' type="button" value="=" onclick="total.value=getTotalB(this.form)" />
<input class='small' type="reset" onClick="reset()" value="-"/>

</form></body></html>
```

That way you can change both buttons at the same time - and they'll look the same (consistency is good practice).

Have some fun with them:

```
<style type='text/css'>
input.small {
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
    width:10px;
}

input.small:hover {
    background:dodgerblue;
}
</style>
```

---

Incidentally, the problem with `style="width"` is that you're telling the button "style yourself with `width`."

The button says "How much `width`? Dunno, I'll just do it the normal way."

To fix that, you need to tell it how wide: `style="width:10px;"`  Now you've got a satisfied button.

Comment: Tried this also, maybe jQuery Mobile is fighting with it?

Answer (score 0):

This code might work:

```
input[type="reset"]{
     width: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input[type=button],input[type=reset] {
 width:10px;
}
```

You can use this if you don't want to resize any of the other type of buttons in your code.
This will work only on type buttons and type reset...or else use classes.